# C# Reflection: does the second DLL file work like the first?

Tags: c#, foreach, reflection

I want to make a simple mod loader, when loading one Dll file - all normal, but when trying to load several all breaks and 2 Dll file gives the same as the first, although they are different. why?

```
private static void Main()
{
    string[] modFolders =
    [
        "Q:\\VisualStudio\\Projects\\C#\\ModLoader\\ModsFolder\\Mod1",
        "Q:\\VisualStudio\\Projects\\C#\\ModLoader\\ModsFolder\\Mod2"
    ];

    foreach (string modFolder in modFolders)
    {
        string dllFile = Directory.GetFiles(modFolder, "*.dll*").First();
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(dllFile);
        Type type = assembly.GetType($"MainMod");

        if (type is not null)
        {
            object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod("Start");
            object result = method.Invoke(instance, null);
            Console.WriteLine($"result: {result}");
        }
    }
}
```

First Dll file:

```
public class MainMod
{
    public static int Start() => 100;
}
```

Second Dll file:

```
public class MainMod
{
    public static string Start() => "Text";
}
```

Output:
100
100

Comment: OT: Don't do this: `"Q:\\VisualStudio\\Projects\\C#\\ModLoader\\ModsFolder\\Mod1"`. Do this: `@"Q:\VisualStudio\Projects\C#\ModLoader\ModsFolder\Mod1"`. Read about verbatim string literals.

Comment: Have you checked the assembly identity? `If an assembly with the same identity is already loaded in the load-from context, LoadFrom returns the loaded assembly even if a different path was specified.`

Comment: Also, you can't have two assemblies with the same classes in scope, that will give all kinds of weird issues. Try changing MainMod in the second dll to some other name.